# error while importing tensorflow version 1.0 gpu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, compiling, cuda

Error message:
I have ubuntu 16.04 with CUDA 8.0 and cuDNN 5.1

Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so.5. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:3517] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library libcuda.so.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: harsh-Inspiron-3542
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:363] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  340.104  Thu Sep 14 17:13:13 PDT 2017
> > >       GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 
> > >       """
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: 340.104.0
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1065] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1066] failed to find libcuda.so on this system: Failed precondition: could not dlopen DSO: libcuda.so.1; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> > >       I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally

Answer (score 0):

Can be found here.
sudo apt install libcuda1-384

Just for completeness the file should be located at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4267